# java changes String during processing?

Tags: java, regex, string, mapping

i have to parse two large text-files. Each file contains a String-Mapping from a local-identifier to a String-value. The local-identifier is in fact just a temporary key. Later the mapping should be from value(file1) to value(file2).

so what i did was:

- build HashMaps with the mappings in every file.
- by iterating over the keyset i build a hashmap which maps value(file1) to value(file2)

after that i had three HashMaps

1. localid -> value(file1)
2. localid -> value(file2)
3. value(file1) -> value(file2)

What i did for verification was: 
for each localid

- a)get value(file1) out of Map 1
- b)get value(file2) out of Map 2
- c)get value(file2) out of Map3 with the key out of step a)
- d)compare value(file2)_b with value(file2)_c

what happens is that the two values in step d) are not equal in 15% of the key-value-pairs.

Actually there is some kind of System there... For example N2c changes into [N]2c, [nH]1c3c changes into n1c3c and (N) changes into ([NH])

is it possible that Java interprets the String as regular expressions or has anyone another idea?

thanks a lot

EDIT: ok here is some code^^ yeah this is more readable... sorry...

```
    HashMap<String, String> idToFile1 = File1.getMapping();
    HashMap<String, String> idToFile2 = File2.getMapping();

    HashMap<String, String> file1ToFile2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(String localid : smilesfragments.keySet()){
        inchiToSmiles.put(idToFile1.get(localid), idToFile2.get(localid));
    }

    for(String localid : idToFile1.keySet()){
        String file1val  = idToFile1.get(localid);
        String file2val = idToFile2.get(localid);
        if(!file2val.equals(file1ToFile2.get(file1val))){
            System.err.println("mismatch!");
        }
    }
```

I get the mismatch in 15% of the cases

Comment: Huh? I understood absolutely nothing. *Actually there is some kind of System there*? Wut?

Comment: Show some code. If you're using String.replaceAll() it takes a regexp, but otherwise Java won't start randomly interpreting Strings as regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If different identifiers can have same values, your third map will keep the last parsed one. E.g. :

File 1 :

- localId1 => "aaaa"
- localId2 => "bbbb"
- localId3 => "cccc"
- localId4 => "aaaa"

File 2:

- localId1 => "1111"
- localId2 => "2222"
- localId3 => "3333"
- localId4 => "4444"

Your first and second maps will store this mapping as it is in your files.

However, when you build your third map, you'll get :

- "aaaa" => "4444"
- "bbbb" => "2222"
- "cccc" => "3333"

As you can see, when you'll verify the parsing of your files, you'll get an error with localId1 ("aaaa" in file 1, "1111" in file 2, but "aaaa" => "4444" in the third map).

**If you can't ensure the uniqueness of the values in your files, you can't store mapping in a map "value in file 1" => "value in file 2".**

This can be an explanation of the 15% errors.

Comment: actually this is exactly what happened -.- The data in the file is incorrect so the mapping is not possible at the moment... Thanks your your answer!